# python selenium scraping from multiple href list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is the url to test
https://stockx.com/puma?prices=300-400,200-300&size_types=men&years=2017

I am able to extract all product detailed page `href` links, however I am only getting one result at the end. It is supposed to go to all the links and extract me the name and img url. What am am I missing here?

Current output result in json

```
[
    {
        "product_name": "Puma Clyde WWE Undertaker Black",
        "imgurl": "https://stockx.imgix.net/Puma-Clyde-WWE-Undertaker-Black.png?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF&w=700&h=500&auto=format,compress&q=90&dpr=2&trim=color&updated_at=1538080256"
    }
]
```

this is the working code

```
import selenium
import json
import time
import re
import string
import requests
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

domain =  'https://stockx.com/puma?prices=300-400,200-300&size_types=men&years=2017'

def prepare_driver(url):
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument('-headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Documents/python/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'title-container')))
    return driver

def fill_form(driver, search_argument):
    '''Finds all the input tags in form and makes a POST requests.'''
    #search_field = driver.find_element_by_id('q')
    #search_field.send_keys(search_argument)
    # We look for the search button and click it
    #driver.find_element_by_class_name('search__submit')\
        #.click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, 'title-container')))
def scrape_results(driver, n_results):
    '''Returns the data from n_results amount of results.'''

    product_urls = list()
    product_data = list()

    for product_title in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class*='tile browse-tile']"):
        product_urls.append(product_title.find_element_by_css_selector(
            "a[href*='/']").get_attribute('href'))
    print(*product_urls, sep = "\n")
    for url in range(0, n_results):
        if url == n_results:
            break
        url_data = scrape_product_data(driver, product_urls[url])
        product_data.append(url_data)
        #print(*product_data, sep = "\n")
        return product_data

def scrape_product_data(driver, product_url):
    '''Visits an product page and extracts the data.'''

    if driver == None:
        driver = prepare_driver(product_url)

    driver.get(product_url)
    time.sleep(12)

    product_fields = dict()
    # Get the product name
    product_fields['product_name'] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//div[@class="col-md-12"]/h1').text

    # Get the image url
    product_fields['imgurl'] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//img[@class="product-image"]').get_attribute('src')
    return product_fields

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        driver = prepare_driver(domain)
        #fill_form(driver, 'juniole tf')
        product_data = scrape_results(driver, 4)
        product_data = json.dumps(product_data, indent=4) #ensure_acii => changes japanese to correct character
        with open('booking_data_stockx.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(product_data)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: I haven't run the code, but I think this is scope related. You aren't appending the next item to your dict(), you're overwriting it each time you find an element.

Comment: its weird because I did the same way with a different website and it worked fine. Itll be nice too see if anyone can run the code when they have time and see if anyone can solve this.

Comment: why can't you take the img url and product names from first page. What is different from the pages you visit?

Comment: I have other data that is only available in the product detail pages. I am first testing it with basic info before developing a more complex code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the whole thing with requests I think.  I chose some random items from the visited pages to prove visited.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
baseURL = 'https://stockx.com'
final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get('https://stockx.com/puma?prices=300-400,200-300&size_types=men&years=2017')
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
    items  = soup.select('#products-container [href]')
    titles = [item['id'] for item in items]
    links = [baseURL + item['href'] for item in items]
    results = list(zip(titles, links))
    df = pd.DataFrame(results) 
    for result in results:
        res = s.get(result[1])
        soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
        details = [item.text for item in soup.select('.detail')]
        final.append([result[0], result[1], details])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(final)
df2.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
```

Comment: thank you very much and wow I did not know this method was much easier and shorter. I wanted to elaborate on your work more. If I can ask a bit more info to scrape. How would I get the info under this container? `details = [item.text for item in soup.select('.pinfo-container')]`.  Additionally what is the best way to dump this information in csv or json or text?

Comment: hi, I will have a look now. What info did you want?

Comment: hi Qharr really appreciate your time. Its these information in the product detail page.
STYLE 364669-04
COLORWAY BLACK/GOLD
RETAIL PRICE $500
RELEASE DATE 2017-04-01

Comment: which url did you pull that from please?

Comment: please see updated answer. You can obviously manipulate the dataframe

Comment: again thank you very much for helping out here.For anyone visiting this thread, my original plan was to use selenium but using `requests` was much easier for my purposes. Hope it helps.